# Output is a list of numbers instead of one total number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very new to programming and I am attempting to do something that is more than likely very simple. I can't seem to find the correct thread though here to show me exactly what I am trying to do or maybe I am searching in the wrong ones.

I am trying to walk through a directory and in doing so count the number of different types of items I am either deleting or moving and have it print out a SINGLE TOTAL AMOUNT instead of it counting up to the final number one by one.

```
    def files_to_be_moved():
        count = 0
        for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk(directory):
            for filename in files:
                if filename.endswith(extensions_to_move):
                    count = count + 1
                    print(count, 'files have been moved')
                    #shutil.move(directory)
```

I would like to see this print out: "237 files have been moved" but instead I get " 1 files have been moved", "2 files have been moved"...ect until it reaches the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the line so that it is outside of the loops:

```
def files_to_be_moved():
    count = 0
    for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith(extensions_to_move):
                count = count + 1
    print(count, 'files have been moved')
    # ^^^
```